# Projections' Angle of Line in Space

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, projection, angle

Start of line (yellow) and axes are at `[xc,yc,zc]`

End of line is at `[xp,yp,zc]`.

`a`,`b`, `c` are the angles which line makes in space.

What I need are the angles which line's projections (black line) create on xy,yz and xz planes.

- `A_y_to_z`: Projected line's angle from y axis to z axis on xz plane.
- `A_z_to_x`: Angle from z to x axis on zx plane.
- `A_x_to_y`: Angle from x to y axis on xy plane.

[image]

Writing code on `Matlab`

Comment: A_x_to_y = atan(y/x). Read somewhere this and tried. But it is not correct.

Comment: @m7913d I have tried on another browser it is visible. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the projection angle to any plane by:

1. Obtaining the direction of the line, `d = (xp - xc, yp - yc, zp - zc)`
2. Normalizing `d`
3. Calculating the *dot-product* with the **normal** of the plane, `dot(d, n) = d.x * n.x + d.y * n.y + d.z * n.z`
4. Calculating the angle to the *normal* by `a = acos(dot(d, n))`
5. Finally obtaining the angle to the plane by taking `b = 90 - a` (assuming units in degrees - NB most math library functions use radians)

Special case: if `dot(d, n) < 0`, then the angle `a` will be greater than 90 degrees. In this case if you only want the acute angle, do `b = a - 90` instead of `90 - a`.

e.g. To calculate the angle to the xy plane, use `n = (0, 0, 1)`, i.e. the z-axis, which is the normal to that plane.