# Rotation of Matrix in Space Results in Moving and do not Rotate to Place on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, geometry, ellipse

Matrix contains the point cloud of surface of ellipsoid. Need to rotate that matrix and centroid should not move anywhere.

Centroid of ellipsoid is at `[xc1,yc1,zc1]`

Rotation should be in such manner that new location of point `[xp1,yp1,zp1]` should be at reference point `[rx,ry,rz]`. Radius of point and reference are equal. Whole matrix will rotate by following the only that point.

To do this task, I have tried to find projections of line from `[xc1,yc1,zc1]` to `[xp1,yp1,zp1]` on xy,yz and xz planes and find the angles. This part done as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905459/projections-angle-of-line-in-space/44905700#44905700). Then repeated same procedure for the line between `[xc1,yc1,zc1]` and `[rx,ry,rz]`.

```
iniV = [xc1 - xp1,yc1 - yp1,zc1 - zp1];
nextV = [xc1 - xr,yc1 - yr,zc1 - zr];

%Projected angles for point
[zRotIni, yRotIni, xRotIni] = projectionAngle(iniV); 
%Projected angles for refence
[zRotNext, yRotNext, xRotNext] = projectionAngle(nextV);
```

I assumed that the difference of angles of point and reference will give me the information how much needed to rotate around each axis. i.e: Angle on yz plane will give the how much needed to rotate around x axis.

```
xRotAngle = xRotNext - xRotIni; 
yRotAngle = yRotNext - yRotIni;
zRotAngle = zRotNext - zRotIni;
```

By using Matlab's functions rotation of matrix done as shown below

```
rX = rotx(xRotAngle);
rY = roty(yRotAngle);
rZ = rotz(zRotAngle);

%vertexT is point cloud matrix
vertexRotT = rX * vertexT; %rotate around x axis
%After rotating around x, rotate around y axis
vertexRotT = rY * vertexRotT; 
vertexRotT = rZ * vertexRotT;
```

The result is shown on below figure. 
[image]

- Blue ellipsoid is the original
- Blue line is point's vector
- Red line is showing the reference line

After rotation, blue and red line should on each other. However whole ellipsoid moved to new place which's centroid coordinate is at `[xc2,yc2,zc2]` and point is at `[xp2,yp2,zp2]`.

As a result, rotation assumption not worked and shape moved to somewhere .However the centroid always should be pinned at `[xc1,yc1,zc1]`

Comment: just a thought: Centre the matrix at [0, 0, 0] -> do your rotation -> bring it back to [xc1,yc1,zc1]

Comment: OK, works. Please answer I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Move the matrix to the origin [0, 0, 0]
2. Perform the rotations
3. Move the matrix back to its initial centre location [xc1,yc1,zc1]